# Are orthogonal spaces exhaustive, i.e. is every vector in either the column space or its orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

Quick question about subspaces, just to make sure I have this straight in my head.

Taking an $n\times k$ matrix X with $rank(X)=k$, is every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in either the column space $C(X)$ (which we know has dimension $k$) or its orthogonal complement the left nullspace $N(X^T)$ (which has dimension $n-k$), or are there some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are in neither?

Another way of asking this I suppose: if you union the subspaces $C(X)$ and $N(X^T)$, is the result all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra

Comment: TPOFOFN, I am actually thinking the answer is no. For example, in $R^3$, I am visualizing a two-dimensional column space which is a plane slicing through $R^3$ which contains the origin. Its orthogonal complement would be the line in $R^3$ which passes through the origin and which is perpendicular to the plane. The only intersection of these two spaces is the zero vector, and all of the vectors in the plane are orthogonal to the vectors in the line. However I can certainly visualize other "slanted" vectors in $R^3$ which are not in either the plane or the line.

Comment: Did you even try to see what happens in an example? Edit: your example is fine.

Comment: Picking up on @Ethan's comment, the **union** (as specified in the OP) of the plane and line is not ${\Bbb R}^3$, but their **direct sum** is: that is, every vector in ${\Bbb R}^3$ can be written as a vector in the plane plus a vector in the line.

Comment: David: Ah! That's right, that makes sense. Thank you for helping me improve my understanding.

Comment: @Ethan, Yes, you are correct that the union (in the formal sense) between the two subspaces is zero.  I took the sense of your question at the end of  the first paragraph "are there some vectors in $R^n$ which are in neither?"  I thought that by using the term *union*, you intended *span*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, but almost.

Consider the function $M:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 }$.  This function is just projection onto the $x$ axis, and so is easy to visualize.

What is the column space (range) of this function?  The $x$-axis, obviously.  What about the left null space?  That is the set of vectors that get mapped to $\mathbb{0}$ by $M^{T}$.  Which is, also, fairly obviously, the $y$-axis.

So, is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?  No, of course not.  But, every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ *is* expressible as the sum of something on the $x$ axis and something on the $y$-axis.  So, the whole space is, not the union, but the *direct sum* of the column space and the left nullspace.

Comment: Your explanation and example made it clear as day. Thank you!

Comment: If $A_{m\times n}$ then $\mathbb{R}^n= Row(A)\oplus Null(A)$ can this be said.